# Ubuntu 18.04- create img file from SD, But different size

Tags: iso, sd-card

I need to clone an OS saved on an SD card ( Raspberry Pi's -`Strech-Lite'),

a) using command line

b) using Ubuntu's `Disk` App

Both done successfully.

But the fact that an 8GB SD creates a 8GB file ( though OS on SD takes only 1 GB appx ), make it impossible to extract this 8GB image file on a 4GB SD.

Hope there is a way to make an img file, at it right size.

Tnx

Guy

EDIT 1:
after minimize using GP:

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you want is to

- If possible, make a **backup** copy (by cloning to another drive of at least the same size) before starting this adventure.
- **Shrink/move the partition(s)** on the 8GB card, so that all the partition(s) end before 4 GB. You can do that with **`gparted`**, when booted from another drive, for example an Ubuntu live drive.
- If there is an MSDOS partition table, that's it, but if there is a GUID partition table, GPT, you must also **repair the backup partition table** at the tail end of the drive. You can do that with `gdisk` or with the shellscript [gpt-fix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative#gpt-fix).
- Now you are ready for cloning, and it should work with `dd`, but is safer to use a tool with a final checkpoint, for example **Disks** alias `gnome-disks`.

Comment: a) using GParted - i minimized SD to 2GB, but afterwards, using DISKS - it still made a BKUP of 8BG- see EDIT1

Comment: by the way- after restoring partition full size, boot failed at final stages :(

Comment: Please explain with more details, what you did and how it failed. Did you clone directly from the source drive (8GB SD card) to the target drive (4 GB SD card)? Or did you clone to an image file, and then cloned from the image file to the target drive (4 GB)? Did you clone the whole drive or did you clone the partitions? Does the original system boot after shrinking the rootfs partition?

Comment: Took the 8GB SD with OS installed, minimized its free space ( as shown in pic ). since it is an OS with some partitions - i need it all clone together.

Comment: @Guy.D, it is correct to clone it all together, `/dev/sdx`, in your screenshot  `/dev/sdd`. Does the original system, I mean the system in the 8 GB card, boot after shrinking the rootfs partition?

Comment: no it was not ( luckily - backed it up prior to change )

Comment: @Guy.D, I guess that is where you broke it. Shrinking a partition should work, but it is risky, so it was a good idea to back it up. You can try again, this time do not touch the head end of the partition where you have the file `grub.cfg`. Do not shrink too much, maybe stay at 3.7 GB to allow for as much free space as possible. (You need a certain amount of free space for the system to work.)

Comment: OK.. will try again. the problem was that still, after changing it to 2 GB, image file was 8GB ( using DISK utility )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80489/discussion-between-sudodus-and-guy-d).